# Can't find gcc compiler

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I am running Fedora 19 via VMware and I want to compile and run, a simple C program. However, after running `which gcc` I get:

```
/usr/bin/which: no gcc in (/home/demetres/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin:/home/demetres/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin_cache:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/demetres/.local/bin:/home/demetres/bin)
```

It hasn't been a long time, since I installed Sourcery CodeBench Lite, an ARM cross-compiler, for a project I'm working on. Is there a problem with cross-compiler? Othewise, what is required to compile and run the program?

p.s. This specific program is not intended for an ARM platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `yum install gcc` for reinstalling.